# How to fix Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: No Database selected

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am using ORM and i am in new in this. I searched alot but nothing found. Please help me to figure out the error

Here is the error

[image]

And Here is the Database connection

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const config = require("../../config/config.json");

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  config.database,
  config.username,
  config.password,
  {
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    port: "80",
    dialect: "mysql",
    operatorAliases: false
  }
);

module.exports = sequelize;
global.sequelize = sequelize;
```

Here is the Model

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

module.exports = sequelize.define("users", {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  email: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  }
});
```

Below is the Query

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var users = require("../src/models/Users");
/* GET home page. */
router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  users.findAll({
    where: {
      id: 1
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: have you made sure your mysql is running on local? Also try using `localhost` if it is running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem isn't with the ORM, instead it is a problem with your connection details.

On what port does your mysql instance running on?
Try the default mysql port: `3306`.

Also, try to test the connection to this port using the command `telnet 127.0.0.1 PORT`
(replace PORT with the port that your mysql instance is running on)

Comment: Yes i check this again, the problem is in connection, thanks